# M-Bus optocoupler application

Tags: circuit-design, uart, opto-isolator

I'm designing an M-bus circuit and when I look at the datasheet, it says I need to use a UART. You can see the connection by looking at the first schematic:

[image: Schematic 1]

When I looked at the same circuit with the optocoupler, the datasheet shows that the M-Bus was connected to the UART pins again. Is UART communication possible with an optocoupler?

[image: Optocoupler Application]

Comment: Is there some reason you think that the schematic with optocouplers won't work?

Comment: @brhans, No, I think it will work. But I don't know how UART communication is possible with optocuopler.

Comment: The schematic you've posted shows how UART communication with optocouplers is possible...

Answer (score 2):

Optocouplers have been used with UARTs for decades, so yes it is possible.